# node-gyp errors while trying to install node modules

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

My environment is Windows 10, and I'm working in cygwin.

When trying to `npm install ldapauth` I get:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\ctote\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:285:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ctote\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\webdev\ldap\node_modules\buffertools
gyp ERR! node -v v7.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN ldap@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN ldap@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! buffertools@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I recently installed `$  npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`, but even before that I was getting some weird errors. I'm not sure what to try, or where to look for these. Below is a larger section of the compile errors, but it looks like general syntax errors based on some messed up library or something?:

```
..\buffertools.cc(19): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\webdev\ldap\node_modules\buffertools\build\buffertools.vcxproj]
  ..\buffertools.cc(32): note: see reference to class template instantiation '`anonymous-namespace'::UnaryAction<Derived>' being compiled
..\buffertools.cc(19): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&' [D:\webdev\ldap\node_modules\buffertools\build\buffertools.vcxproj]
..\buffertools.cc(21): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\webdev\ldap\node_modules\buffertools\build\buffertools.vcxproj]
..\buffertools.cc(21): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&' [D:\webdev\ldap\node_modules\buffertools\build\buffertools.vcxproj]
..\buffertools.cc(35): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int [D:\webdev\ldap\node_modules\buffertools\build\buffertools.vcxproj]
  ..\buffertools.cc(60): note: see reference to class template instantiation '`anonymous-namespace'::BinaryAction<Derived>' being compiled
..\buffertools.cc(35): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '&' [D:\webdev\ldap\node_modules\buffertools\build\buffertools.vcxproj]
```